# using val() with jquery // input text dissappear with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an input box, where i would like a text to disappear.
After googling around i found a nice solution over here:
[Fade out text value inside of text field using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066434/fade-out-text-value-inside-of-text-field-using-jquery)

However, for some reason it does not work with my code over here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var input = $("#textboxid").val()
  input.animate({color:'white'},1000, function(){
    $(this).val('').css('color','black');
  }
});
```

Could you tell where i'm mistaken? 
thank you

EDIT: 
The text should disappear after user typed something in.

Comment: you can not animate text inside text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some syntax errors in your script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var input = $("#textboxid"); //you have to use the object here and not the value-string
    input.animate({
        color: '#FFF'
    }, 1000, function () {
        $(this).val('').css('color', 'black');
    }); //the bracket was missing here
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aLdmxk7s/)

Furthermore jQuery don't support the animation of the color-attribute.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1354277/4202224) for more information.

See this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zcqdmfxr/2/) for the animation with the included jQuery-UI Library.

**Reference**

[.animate](http://jqueryui.com/animate/)

Comment: got the animate, and corrected the mistakes, thanks!  It looks like text does not disappears on the demo.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov, in which demo the text did not disappear and what do expect when to happen ?

Comment: hups, did not see the test to disappear, my bad

Answer (score 1):

val() gets the *value* of the textbox, that is what's written inside it. It's a string. You can't animate a string, you can animate a jQuery object.

Don't take `$("#textboxid").val()`, just take `$("#textboxid")`.

EDIT :

I made it simply using just CSS3. This does not require any library and is hardware accelerated.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    $("input").css("color", "white");
});
```

```css
input {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="some value"/>
<button>Fade it away</button>
```

Comment: if i take $("#textboxid"), the whole box disappears, while i want the text to disappear. Have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/7ksWA/1/ there it seems like the text disappears.

Comment: Got it. I have updated my answer. Just use a CSS3 transition.